# A sequence of numbers prime to $4n$ with $n$ being odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be odd. If I consider the sequence of $n$ numbers in the form $4k-1$ with $k$ running from $1$ to $n$ and take those with greatest common divisor with $4n$ being $1$ ( means those being prime to $4n$ ) I get exactly $\phi(n)$ of them.

I miss now a proof/argument why this true.

I tested the case $n=15$.

Comment: To rephrase for my own benefit: Why is $\{ 4k - 1 : 1 \leq k \leq n, (4k-1, 4n) =1\}$ of size $\phi(n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that since $4k-1$ is odd, we have $(4n, 4k-1) = (n, 4k-1)$.

Now, if any $4k-1 \equiv 4i-1 \pmod{n}$, then $k \equiv i \pmod{n}$ (because $4$ is invertible mod $n$). Therefore before we select the numbers which have $(4n, x) = 1$, our list consists of numbers which are all different modulo $n$. (Since $(n, a) = (n, a-n)$, it's enough to consider the list mod $n$.)

There are certainly $n$ of them, so that list must just be the numbers $1, \dots, n$ in some order (mod $n$).

Now if we select the ones which are coprime to $n$, we must get a list of length $\phi(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f_4: \mathbb{Z}_{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n},\;f_4(k) \equiv 4k-1 \pmod n$ is a bijection because $\gcd(4,n)=1$. The same applies if you substitute $4$ with any number $m$ with $\gcd(n,m)=1,\,$ and the additive constant $1$ can be replaced be any number. 
Check this e.g. for $n=15, m=7, f(k) = 7k+4$